# Force Windows 8 to ignore EDID and output 5.1 over HDMI

Tags: windows, audio, hdmi, nvidia-geforce

I have a Windows 8 system with an nVidia 660 video card connected over HDMI to my Vizio television, which is connected via optical output to a 5.1 system.

I cannot get my computer to output 5.1 in this configuration, and I believe it's because my Vizio is reporting itself as a 2 channel device, so Windows will only output 2 channel to it.

I know if I force 5.1 on a PS3 or 360 connected to the TV, my 5.1 system receives all 5.1 channels.

How can I force Windows or my nVidia card to output 5.1? For reference, here's my sound properties pane:

[image: E601i-A3-1 Properties]

- My 5.1 system is actually a soundbar, and my TV has all the HDMI inputs - to save swapping cables I have to go through the TV
- This may look like a duplicate, but that's because I asked the question already [here](https://superuser.com/questions/579400/how-can-i-force-5-1-output-over-hdmi-on-my-geforce-660-in-windows-8) where it was falsely marked as a duplicate - I can't install ATI drivers for my nVidia card.

Comment: You should flag your original question to be reopened, or post about it on meta.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem using a Radeon 7790.How I fixed it? Spent $14 and bought a Rocket Pro by Belkin. Hooked it up and all 5.1 channels are enabled. It works in all systems that I know of. You can buy them at Amazon.com

Comment: I can't find a "Belkin Rocket Pro" on Amazon - is this what you're talking about? http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-av10115-2-SWITCH-1-OUT-BLACK/dp/B008M11XPA/